# oddstream error for get_pc_space()

Tags: r, time-series, pca, multivariate-analysis, anomaly-detection

I am trying out the 'oddstream' package for anomaly detection in a collection of time series data streams, following the example here - https://github.com/pridiltal/oddstream

I am now trying the same process in the example, but using my own generated data, which consists of 4 data streams, each with a numeric double value per minute. Following the example I have pivoted the data per time series, removed the timestamp and now my data is in an object called 'data_values' in this format;

```
"thanos","ironman","captain_america","hulk"
3.7933707,10.164239,12.514751,9.689982
4.5170693,15.88197,10.431008,8.345579
4.258799,15.741869,12.244887,11.037741
4.0412955,11.823674,9.517862,11.15495
4.2847366,13.72516,11.089338,13.155646
4.076619,10.513271,17.092613,12.405578
3.6052873,14.222145,11.051033,9.765422
3.9812086,17.19401,13.004522,13.648401
3.72212,11.095416,11.487545,14.012459
4.5084734,12.152,14.038413,12.560803
3.8176696,11.412605,10.385266,12.806011
4.3973894,13.509395,13.644381,10.491239
4.058119,14.249434,11.672884,11.187779
4.161111,14.844873,15.815558,14.559033
3.8905697,11.550871,15.815259,12.187394
6.5188656,6.389417,15.472974,12.524681
5.4459763,13.383606,16.610128,13.659021
6.722979,12.058713,12.0502825,16.697142
5.9772997,16.411823,12.592097,14.264039
6.3547525,13.261564,12.283675,11.7058735
```

There are 10057 rows however I get the error I am struggling with using only this subset too. So using this subset above, I can extract the time series features;

```
features <- extract_tsfeatures(data_values[1:20,1:4])
features
```

which brings back the 14 column matrix;

```
"mean","variance","lumpiness","lshift","vchange","linearity","curvature","spikiness","BurstinessFF","minimum","maximum","rmeaniqmean","moment3","highlowmu"
4.60668556,1.00702326532496,0.855366442741394,1.05557524,1.30794987881141,3.04846236351802,1.8476299661999,0.000554329483171873,0.218600391150848,3.6052873,6.722979,0.913879392280466,111.639461480883,3
12.97930275,6.4034605328223,0.703054250578798,0.544145299999998,1.18579445991183,-0.820696245222748,1.50118483843438e-11,0.279156869117938,0.49335936268397,6.389417,17.19401,1.02644843537531,954.355024327516,0.818181818181817
12.940723825,4.87480320180651,0.000131101403724768,1.38705325,0.0161926775874006,3.64250957492454,-6.02729157599105e-11,0.0775880978567155,0.376702514305185,9.517862,17.092613,0.958154518068467,1065.07723774107,1.5
12.292938675,3.82434122626332,0.020330298422021,1.43056515,0.201644729274142,5.00995054716844,-1.50214890817974e-10,0.0183924722110376,0.311100651143802,8.345579,16.697142,1.01400729553383,1018.68114519884,0.818181818181818
```

However when I run the next step using the features matrix;

```
pc <- get_pc_space(features)
```

I get the following error;

```
Error in pcaPP::PCAproj(features, k = ncol(features), scale = sd, center = mean) : 
  k too large
```

It gets stuck on this method - https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pcaPP/versions/1.9-73/topics/PCAproj where k is the number of components to produce. 
I understand that 'k' is set in this example to the number of columns in features, which as far as I can tell is 14, and my features object matches the structure I get when I run the github 'anomalous_stream' example. The difference is that the github example does not throw an error here despite 'k' presumably being exactly the same.
I am a bit stuck on what the issue is, if anyone would be able to help - many thanks!

**UPDATE 1:**

Looking at the source code for the PCAproj() method [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/pcaPP/src/R/PCAproj.R);

```
n = nrow (x)
p = ncol (x)

if( k > min(n,p))
    stop ('k too large')
```

As I only have 4 time series, that means my features object which is the 'x' input into the method, only has 4 rows. As the error shows that k is set to k = ncol(features), which is 14, does this mean that I need at least 14 rows and therefore 14 time series in order for k to not be too large?

**UPDATE 2 - Resolved:**

I have created another 12 time series to take my total up to 16, and this is now working.
If anyone else comes across this issue, the features matrix will produce 14 columns, and you need at least this number of time series in order to be able to apply the get_pc_space() method to the features matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for this question.  Now  I have updated the [get_pc_space() function](https://github.com/pridiltal/oddstream/blob/master/R/get_pc_space.R) based on this question. Now it has the ability to produce a two dimensional PC space even for a small collection of time series (less than 14 time series).

The main objective of the oddstream framework (as explained here https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10618600.2019.1617160?journalCode=ucgs20) is to detect anomalous time series within a “large” collection of streaming time series. In our previous implementation of oddstream package there was an additional assumption that the number of time series in the large collection of time series is greater than the number of features ( 14 in the current oddstream package implementation).  get_pc_space()  function was developed as a part of this framework. Therefore in the previous implementation, there should be  at least 14 number of time series in order to be able to apply the get_pc_space()  to the features matrix.

Now I have updated the get_pc_space() function (in the GitHub version of this package) (https://github.com/pridiltal/oddstream/blob/master/R/get_pc_space.R)  such that it can deal with small collection of time series  (less than 14 time series)).

Comment: Thanks so much for your response and link to your paper, which I have been reading alongside trying out the package :) I understand I was using far too small a sample set and the purpose of the package is to be able to detect anomalies within a large collection. It is all very interesting.
I have also just had the below error when trying out the find_odd_streams() method when including the argument 'concept_drift = TRUE';

Error in update_anom_threshold(outliers, series, pc, pctest, p_rate, trials,  : 
  object 'ktest' not found

Comment: I think my outliers are not meeting any of the conditions for the ktest object and so it stops producing the outlier matrix. I am still looking into this though so not sure what the issue is.
Thanks again